# PHP Date difference of two given date

Tags: php

I want two date difference in number of days in php. Following is the code which works perfectly for rest of the given date except 32 in days. I know in english there is no 32 in days but i am using Nepali Date to store in db. In Nepali calendar there is 32 days also, so i need help from anyone.

```
   $dStart = new DateTime('2071-02-32');
   $dEnd  = new DateTime('2071-02-31');
   $dDiff = $dStart->diff($dEnd);
   echo $dDiff->days; //output should come 1
```

Comment: Already answered the same question [Click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

Comment: @varunsinghal read the question again, and again!

Comment: Convert to the gregorian date. Run the calculation in php and then convert the date back to Nepalese

Answer (score 3):

I Guess, you probably already using converter (Nepali Dates to English Dates), to handle them. If not, use this one [Nepali Date Convert](https://github.com/amant/Nepali-Date-Convert)

and you can simply convert you nepali dates to english, before calculating difference, see example below:

```
$calendar = new Nepali_Calendar();
$date1 = $calendar->nep_to_eng('2071', '02', '32');
$date2 = $calendar->nep_to_eng('2071', '02', '31');

$dStart = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-n-j', $date1['year'].'-'.$date1['month'].'-'.$date1['date']);
$dEnd  = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-n-j', $date2['year'].'-'.$date2['month'].'-'.$date2['date']);
$dDiff = $dStart->diff($dEnd);
echo $dDiff->days;
```

Comment: Actually i need the two date difference in number of days. I don't need date converter...

Comment: Yes, for that too you need to use date converter as php doesn't understand Nepali dates.

Answer (score 0):

Below code works fine:

```
function diff($time1, $time2, $precision = 6) {
    // If not numeric then convert texts to unix timestamps
    if (! is_int ( $time1 )) {
        $time1 = strtotime ( $time1 );
    }
    if (! is_int ( $time2 )) {
        $time2 = strtotime ( $time2 );
    }

    // If time1 is bigger than time2
    // Then swap time1 and time2
    if ($time1 > $time2) {
        $ttime = $time1;
        $time1 = $time2;
        $time2 = $ttime;
    }

    // Set up intervals and diffs arrays
    $intervals = array (
            'year',
            'month',
            'day',
            'hour',
            'minute',
            'second' 
    );
    $diffs = array ();

    // Loop thru all intervals
    foreach ( $intervals as $interval ) {
        // Set default diff to 0
        $diffs [$interval] = 0;
        // Create temp time from time1 and interval
        $ttime = strtotime ( "+1 " . $interval, $time1 );
        // Loop until temp time is smaller than time2
        while ( $time2 >= $ttime ) {
            $time1 = $ttime;
            $diffs [$interval] ++;
            // Create new temp time from time1 and interval
            $ttime = strtotime ( "+1 " . $interval, $time1 );
        }
    }

    $count = 0;
    $times = array ();
    // Loop thru all diffs
    foreach ( $diffs as $interval => $value ) {
        // Break if we have needed precission
        if ($count >= $precision) {
            break;
        }
        // Add value and interval
        // if value is bigger than 0
        if ($value > 0) {
            // Add s if value is not 1
            if ($value != 1) {
                $interval .= "s";
            }
            // Add value and interval to times array
            $times [] = $value . " " . $interval;
            $count ++;
        }
    }

    // Return string with times
    return implode ( ", ", $times );
}

$startTime = '09-10-2017 10:30 AM';
$endTime = '19-10-2017 04:30PM';
// Run and print diff
echo 'Span: '.diff ( $startTime, $endTime, 6 );
```